# GPU, Nvidia GEFORCE GT 1030 by Gigabyte - not booting to log in screen

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, graphics

just bought a new GPU, Nvidia GEFORCE GT 1030 by Gigabyte. (supports openGL 4.5
I cant boot into ubuntu 16.04 with it plugged in. ive swapped back to old GPU for now so iu can boot in. i get past all the initialisation, just freezes before the log in screen. I tried failsafe graphics mode but i cant navigate the video settings window that comes up..........i also just bought a new 4K monitor that works under old GPU... cant find any linux support for the GPU.

what should i try?

Using GA-X79-UP4 - Gigabyte motherboard

with i7-4820K CPU

Thanks!!

Comment: You may need nomodeset to boot installer & first boot once installed or until you can install driver per answer below. At grub menu you can use e for edit, scroll to linux line and replace quiet splash with nomodeset.
How to set NOMODESET and other kernel boot options in grub2 - both BIOS liveCD & grub first boot ( also UEFI with grub) 
How to add boot parameters,  grub menu after install (also grub when UEFI)
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters &

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed a driver?

If not add the ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

Then add the driver

`sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430 nvidia-settings`

Note that if you want a different driver version edit the 430 accordingly

Comment: cant find package if i use my model number, unfortunately

Comment: The 430 is the driver version not the card model number. It’s not very old so should support your card along with many other nvidia cards

Comment: @FrannyDimitri the kernel could also be what's at fault here. any reason why your ubuntu 16 is an ubuntu 16 instead of an ubuntu 19?

Comment: @ tatsu  because 18.04 doesnt output thru my subwoofer output via my mobo soundchip.  i havnt tried 19.10.  i only use LTS editions

Comment: @PonJar  oh ok, will try in the morning, ive already installed! thanks heaps hey!!